# Differences between restricted repositories and partner repositories?

Tags: repository, official-repositories

In /etc/apt/source.list, what are differences between restricted repositories and partner repositories?

They both don't make their source open, do they? Are they both free of money? Difference in freedom to use, modify, and/or redistribute their software? Difference in maintenance/support level and party?

Comment: seems like too broad..

Comment: This would be better at Ubuntu forums or Discourse. Or remove any 4 questions to make it suitable for Q/A format.

Comment: The question really should be about multiverse and partner. Restricted contains software "that is not available under a completely free license" according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu. Multiverse contains software "that is not free".

Answer (score 8):

The restricted archive may contain only hardware drivers, not application software. It comes as a compromise in recognition that potential Ubuntu users could not use Ubuntu at all without it. Source: [Ubuntu Policy Manual section 2.2.2](http://people.canonical.com/~cjwatson/ubuntu-policy/policy.html/ch-archive.html#s-restricted).

The Canonical partner repository is not part of Ubuntu. It contains anything that Canonical thinks might be useful to Ubuntu users that is not Free Software. This includes application software.

So: restricted is a compromise in Ubuntu to make hardware work, and is restricted to just this. Canonical's partner repository is not part of Ubuntu, but may contain a wider range of non-free software.